# Recently Viewed Products in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to be able to clear recently viewed products when I click on a link `Clear Recently Viewed Products`.

When customers login and view some products in Magento then Magento displays recently viewed products on the right side. I would like to add one link under that recently viewed products block which when clicked - it should remove/clear all the recently viewed products from that right block and it should show `"There are no recently viewed product available"` message there.

```
 $_products = $this->getRecentlyViewedProducts();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently viewed products data are stored in this table `report_viewed_product_index`.

So simply you can delete those records based on customer_id.